# Spring JPA native query to '@IdClass' annotated table and getting "No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111"

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working with a postgres 10.13 , Spring boot starter 2.27 and hibernate-core-5.4.15 versions.
recently I had to use a native query with several joins to pull out set of UUIDs. it did not worked out and got "No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111" error. I checked with a simple select query as follows and still am getting the same error. Can you please let me know a clue what will  cause this error? this will work for normal tables and since in this case I need to query the table annotated with "@IdClass".

Entity Class -

```
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
@Audited
@AuditOverride(forClass = UpdatableEntity.class)
public class Book extends UpdatableEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @org.hibernate.annotations.Generated(value = GenerationTime.INSERT)
  @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "pg-uuid")
  private UUID id;

  private UUID bookOwner;

  private String commennts;

  private int rating;

  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<BookResource> resources = new ArrayList<>();

  }
```

Mapping Id class -

```
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "book_resource")
@IdClass(BookResourceIdClass.class)
@Audited
@AuditOverride(forClass = UpdatableEntity.class)
public class BookResource extends UpdatableEntity {

  @Id private UUID book;

  @Id private UUID resource;
}
```

ID class -

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BookResourceIdClass implements Serializable {

  @Id private UUID book;

  @Id private UUID resource;
}
```

JPA Repository class

```
  @Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, UUID> {
  
  @Query(value = "select aa.book " 
      + " from book_resource aa where aa.resource = :resource", nativeQuery = true)
  List<UUID> findBook(@Param("resource") UUID resource);
}
```

Error -

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.JdbcResultMetadata.getHibernateType(JdbcResultMetadata.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(ScalarResultColumnProcessor.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:494)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:2338)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2294)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2131)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1163)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
```

Highly appreciate your thoughts regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: @SternK It is "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"

Comment: @SternK .. Thank you very much.. yes, I used to convert it to "varchar" instead of UUID and got the List of String Ids from the query and it worked. then from the code I had to reconvert those String Ids to UUID again. Thats why I thought of doing something wrong in the first place and I suspect this happens to the tables that used underneath "@IdClass" classes. Looks like simple select * query will give this "No Dialect" error. Not sure though. Thank you very much for your inputs. Please share anything if you find. Appreciate your support.